# How long is an NCD valid for?

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance, vehicle

If I had a car policy expire on 22nd May 2019 that had 3 years no claims, how long is this 3 years no claims valid for to use with a new policy ?

Is it just my next insurance policy ?

What if I started a new policy, but after 9 months realised I could get a much better deal else where with 3 yrs NCD, would the 3 years NCD still be valid, and if so for how long ?

This is for UK car insurance, just a standard fully comprehensive policy for a single driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### “No claims” discounts are not regulated yet law

**They are a business practice offered by each individual insurer**

As such you need to read their policy documents to find out how or if it works.

Comment: yeah after a bit more digging I found a useful link that says most companies allow for a 2 year gap, but it  really is dependant on each insurers terms

Answer (score 0):

No claims discount is valid until you make a claim. (You can also pay some extra fee so that one claim in some time frame doesn't affect your claim). So if you move insurance, stay with the new insurance for a year without a claim, then you have four years "no claims" discount for your next insurance.

Comment: I want to move after 9 months with new insurer, obviously I cant carry 3yrs and 9 months, so is my 3 yrs still 'transferable' ?